# How to replace multiple instances of a sub string in a long string (html template) with a list of strings in order?

Tags: python, html, string, for-loop

I'm trying to write a text file web document using python (First year uni student learning the basic concepts of python)

Say I have a HTML template like this:

```
<!DOCTYPEhtml>
<html>
<head>
    <title>News Archive</title>
</head>

<body> 
  <br>
  <ol>

  <!--  Article 1 -->

  <h1>***TITLE***</h1>


  <img src=***IMGURL***  
  <p>***DESCRIPTION***</p>
  <p><strong> Full story: </strong> ***LINK*** </p>
  <p><strong> Dateline: </strong> ***PUBDATE*** </p>
  <br/>
  <!--  Article 2 -->  
  <h1>***TITLE***</h1>
  <img src=***IMGURL***   

  <p>***DESCRIPTION***</p>

  <p><strong> Full story: </strong> ***LINK*** </p>
  <p><strong> Dateline: </strong> ***PUBDATE*** </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Lets say I want to replace all instances of `\*\**TITLE***` with strings in a list in order. Here is the list containing strings:

```
titles = ['HI', 'HELLO']
```

How would i replace the first instance of ***TITLE*** with `'HI'` and the second instance of `\*\**TITLE***` with `'HELLO'`?

I've tried this basic for loop but I don't think I have done it correctly (Since I'm only learning basics of python, i think the teacher wants a for-loop)

```
for tags in range(2):
    html_code = html_template.replace('***TITLE***', titles)
```

Thanks in advance. (PS: Sorry for terrible formatting, new to stack overflow)

***EDIT: Sorry forgot to mention crucial detail...***
What if i wanted to create a for loop that replaces for example ***TITLE*** with its respective 2 string list, ***IMGURL*** with its respective 2 string list, ***DESCRIPTION*** with its respective 2 string list, and so on for the rest of the placeholders?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify how many occurrences you want to replace:

```
for t in titles:
    html_template = html_template.replace('***TITLE***', t, 1)
```

Comment: @navre3 this will replace the first occurrence of `'***TITLE***'` with the first item in `t` and so on.

Comment: What if i wanted to create a for loop that replaces for example \*\**TITLE*** with its respective 2 string list, \*\**IMGURL*** with its respective 2 string list, \*\**DESCRIPTION*** with its respective 2 string list, and so on for the rest of the placeholders?